# openlayers - filter specific feature(s) from ol.Collection

Tags: openlayers

I have a feature collection (ol.Collection) contains number of points, lines and polygons features that originated from interactive drawing.

I want filter/select  only for a certain geometry (e.g. Linestring) to write in GeoJSON format (All I can do now is looping on feature id via getFeatureById() methods)

is there any way to filter feature(s) based on its geometry type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check that by [instanceof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) comparing your geometry to ol.geom[type] where type is string representation of your type (see below). This example should do it:

```
function filterGeometry(collection,type){ 
  var selectedFeatures = []; 
  var featArray = collection.getArray();
  for(var i = 0;i<featArray.length;i++){
    if(featArray[i].getGeometry() instanceof ol.geom[type]){
      selectedFeatures.push(featArray[i]); 
    } 
  } 
  return selectedFeatures;//returns array of features with selected geom type 
} 
var yourCollection = new ol.Collection();//your ol.Collection with data 
var onlyLineStringArray = filterGeometry(yourCollection,"LineString");
var GeoJSONFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var GeoJSONString = GeoJSONFormat.writeFeatures(onlyLineStringArray);
```

Types are e.g.: Polygon, LineString, Point, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon, Circle etc., complete list of geometry types is [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.html).

Comment: great!!! works like charm